# Mysqli commit in other function

Tags: php, mysqli, commit

I have a PHP class with many functions and this is my problem:

In function A i do some steps for prepare an insert into database
But I DON'T commit because I want do it in an other function (B function) like this code.
But in the data base no one  row is inserted.

Any idea?

Thanks to all, this is my sample code:

```
public static function functionA($id, $email, $password, $name, $surname) {

    global $mysqli;

    $mysqli = self::getDb(); //with $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE); 

    if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO User (Id, mail, Password, Name, Surname) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)'))){

           self::closeDatabase($mysqli, $stmt);
           die;
    }

    if (!$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $id, $email, $password, $name, $surname)) {

        self::closeDatabase($mysqli, $stmt);
        die;
    }

    if (!$stmt->execute()) {

        self::closeDatabase($mysqli, $stmt);
        die;
    }

}
public static function functionB() {

    global $mysqli;

    $mysqli->commit();

    self::closeDatabase($mysqli, $stmt);
}
```

Comment: How about _using a property_, and never using `global`?

Comment: Please add some code and query examples to your question.

Comment: now i posted a simple code, thanks

Comment: I assume it is not a real code you are using? It is no use to post it then

Comment: i only changed the name of the functions for semplify, the rest is exactly like my code

Answer (score 0):

Change this code

```
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO User (Id, mail, Password, Name, Surname) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)'))){


    self::closeDatabase($mysqli, $stmt);
    die;
}
```

to this one:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO User (Id, mail, Password, Name, Surname) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)';
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)))
{
    throw new Exception($mysqli->error." [$sql]");
}
```

for ALL your queries.
Then make sure you can see PHP errors.
Then run your code again.

Comment: i think that the problem is only in separate commit of the rest because if i put commit in functionA  the insert query run fine...

Comment: Programmer should never *think.* But know for sure.

Comment: i changed my code with your suggestion but i have the same result..the query work only if commit is in functionA

Comment: Then you have to make sure it's the same mysqli instance. do `var_dump($mysqli);` and check the number after # for both variables